# backlinks from hidden iframe to one page of my site.Has a positive or negative effect on my site seo?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks, ranking, iframe

i have more than 60000 backlink too one page of my site because i put a hidden iframe in my free products. like this:

```
<IFRAME style="display:none;" SRC="http://www.domain.com/df/sdff.html" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1></IFRAME>
```

this backlinks Has positive or negative impact on my site ranking & seo ?